# Merge 2 text files with the same first column

Tags: arrays

I need to merge this 2 files

File1

1

1

2

2

2

3

4

4

4

File2

1  A  0.2  0.8  0.3

2  B  0.4  0.3  0.2

3  C  0.8  0.9  0.5

4  D  0.6  0.7  0.8

Output should be

1  A  0.2  0.8  0.3

1  A  0.2  0.8  0.3

2  B  0.4  0.3  0.2

2  B  0.4  0.3  0.2

2  B  0.4  0.3  0.2

3  C  0.8  0.9  0.5

4  D  0.6  0.7  0.8

4  D  0.6  0.7  0.8

4  D  0.6  0.7  0.8

Comment: In which programming language? Also, have you [**tried anything so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)?

Comment: Is this homework ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python and pandas then it's not too difficult I guess

```
d1 = pd.read_csv('doc1.txt',sep=" ",header=None)
d2 = pd.read_csv('doc2.txt',sep= " ",header=None)
data = d1.merge(d2,on=[0],how='left')
print(data)
```

There will be NAN values in data if second file does not have corresponding indices if you don't want that, you can change the type of join